# Event handler re-use in Javascript

Tags: javascript, beginner, object-oriented, jquery, event-handling

I've been trying to deal with a lot of duplicate code in the first web pages I've been working on and have been playing around with the prototype model, which I think is the 'right' way to go about it.

What I'm not sure about however is if this is the right way to re-use **event handlers**. For example:

```
function GeneralPageHandler(args) {
  this.args = args;

  this.eventHandlers();
}

GeneralPageHandler.prototype.eventHandlers = function() {
    $('#OK').click(function() {
      //Do something
    });
}

function SpecificPageHandler(args) {
  this.args = args;
  this.prototype = Object.create(GeneralPageHandler.prototype);
  this.prototype.constructor = GeneralPageHandler;

  GeneralPageHandler.call(this, this.args);
}

SpecificPageHandler.prototype.eventHandlers = function() {
  GeneralPageHandler.eventHandlers.call(this);

  $('#Select').change(function() {
    //Do something
  });
  $('#OK').click(function() {
    //Do something that might be different to the previous click handler
  }
}
```

For the most part this allows me to re-use event handlers for common page elements, but I have found I end up with multiple handlers being defined for the same elements, depending on the specific page's purpose.
I also find that I'm sometimes 'inheriting' event handlers which I don't particularly need on a specific page, but I think this might be more my misuse of the prototype model than anything else.

Does this seem a sensible way to go about re-using event handlers? Are there any ways that I could make this pattern more robust?

Comment: With all due respect, your question is a little on the vague side. I invite you to post a pair of specific HTML pages, and specific handlers that they use. Maybe you're validating input or choosing calendar dates or something. The specific thing I'm looking for is how much overlap in variables and functionality there is between the two pages, how much opportunity for reuse there is. I'm trying to see if they compose, if it makes sense to call fn1 and separately fn2 because they are orthogonal, or if there is some linkage between them.